# iOS 7 crashes when opening Ionic/Cordova Tutorial App

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, crash, ionic-framework

My iPad crashed a few times when opening this [Todo App](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/preface.html). It freezes and I have to do a hard reboot, every time. I don't know yet how to reproduce it, but it has happened right after opening the app (probably when opening it again right after closing it).

Here's the device log from Xcode:

```
Incident Identifier: 8744B814-F76D-42C0-B50B-C530C52F2E57
CrashReporter Key:   352890f9ff60b67e52be2333d0572da290ba2145
Hardware Model:      iPad2,4
Process:             HelloCordova [198]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/01FE4748-902C-4CC5-92BE-7006F2CA2E06/HelloCordova.app/HelloCordova
Identifier:          com.ionicframework.starter
Version:             1.0 (0.0.1)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-06-04 19:01:57.150 -0300
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.ionicframework.starter failed to launch in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 2.640 (user 2.640, system 0.000), 6% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.000, 0% CPU

Backtrace not available

No thread state (register information) available
Binary Images:
0x2be5a000 - 0x2be7afff dyld armv7  <651a31c39f71311f965f8ac44de02c88> /usr/lib/dyld
```

I have no idea how to debug that. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

The iPad crashed once again when running the same sample app from Xcode. It trashed on Cordova's splashscren.

Here's what `idevicesyslog` said:

```
Jun  6 15:32:19 iPad-de-MFX com.apple.debugserver-310.2[314] <Warning>: About to launch process for bundle ID: com.ionicframework.starter
Jun  6 15:32:28 iPad-de-MFX com.apple.debugserver-310.2[314] <Error>: error: timed out trying to send openApplication to com.ionicframework.starter.
Jun  6 15:32:28 iPad-de-MFX com.apple.debugserver-310.2[314] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [013a/060b]: RNBRunLoopLaunchInferior DNBProcessLaunch() returned error: 'timed out trying to launch app'
Jun  6 15:32:28 iPad-de-MFX com.apple.debugserver-310.2[314] <Warning>: error: failed to launch process /Developer/usr/bin/debugserver: timed out trying to launch app
Jun  6 15:32:28 iPad-de-MFX com.apple.debugserver-310.2[314] <Warning>: 2 +0.002965 sec [013a/1207]: error: ::read ( -1, 0x4069ec, 18446744069414585344 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Jun  6 15:32:28 iPad-de-MFX com.apple.debugserver-310.2[314] <Warning>: Exiting.
```

Comment: I don't have an iPad 2 I could test on, but an app crash (which it looks like is occurring - the watchdog timer is catching it, I think) should *never* freeze your device. You might want to check your device's logs (other than just the crash log) and see if something else is going on.

Comment: thanks. i'm using [this](https://github.com/benvium/libimobiledevice-macosx) now and i'll get back here with more info if it happens again.